# MySQL extremely slow on a simple query

Tags: mysql

I did a very simple query on my table in MySQL using following SQL

```
SELECT count(1) from allchangefiles;
```

and this one took almost half hour to finish. Following is what showed in my terminal:

```
mysql> select count(1) from allchangefiles;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|  3047591 |
+----------+
1 row in set (23 min 13.22 sec)
```

I think this is ridiculous, any suggestion?

```
mysql> explain select count(1) from allchangefiles;
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  |    rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | allchangefiles | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |  3429648 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question and insert the result of `explain select count(1) from allchangefiles;`?

Comment: If you're unsure what that "explain" means, "The EXPLAIN statement can be used to obtain information about how MySQL executes a statement." [Here's more](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: I added the result of EXPLAIN